# Hibernate multiple Sessions with different Users

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I am building my first Java Application with Hibernate and have a bit of a problem with Hibernate Sessions.

My Problem:
When a second User logs into the application he overrides the session for the first user -> both are working on the second session now. Although both Users create a new Session when logging in.

My Code:

first I get the current User when the user logs in (LoginDetail.java):

```
userBean = UserProxy.getInstance().getElementByUser(userBean.getUser(), userBean.getPassword());
```

UserProxy.java:

```
public static synchronized UserProxy getInstance() {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new UserProxy();
    }

    return instance;
}
public UserBean getElementByUser(String user, String password) {

    try {
        Iterator<SUsers> iter = s.createQuery("from SUsers where user = '" + user + "' and password = '" + password + "'").list().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            userDB = iter.next();
            currentUser = convertClassToBean(userDB);
            log.debug("aktuell ausgewaehlter char: " + userDB.getId());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    currentUser = convertClassToBean(userDB);

    return currentUser;
}
```

My HibernateUtil.java:

```
public static final ThreadLocal<Session>    session = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
public static Session currentSession() {
    Session s = session.get();
    // Open a new Session, if this Thread has none yet
    if (s == null) {
        s = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.set(s);
    }
    return s;
}
```

and the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hey which session are you talking about.I guess there should be any issues returning same hibernate session w/o being concern which user is logged in

Comment: The current User is stored in the session. That way I decide what to show the current User. So at the moment when a second user logs in the first user is in the same session and sees everything from the second user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, creating session is a lightweight operation (Hibernate docs) so it is not a performance hit to create new session every time you need it UNLESS you gonna use it let's just say more than 100 times per second.
The proper way for this is that your HibernateUtil does not return session, but session factory instead. SessionFactory is ThreadSafe so don't worry about concurrency. You should create new session for your requests using factory, query DB and close it to return connection into hibernate's connection pool. Pattern:

1. Get factory
2. Open session
3. Query your DB
4. Close session

Comment: Thank you for your post this helps for my understanding! But I'm still not sure how to proceed. I want the currentUser to be stored in the session the whole time while the user is working on the application, so I dont currently close the session.

How would I achieve that a user stays logged in w/o an open session?

Comment: You are missleading yourself into a trap. Dont confuse hibernate session with the user session (eg. php session, or any other session type). In my answer I mention Hibernate session which is related ONLY to database, not user application session. It has nothing in common with keeping current user identity alive.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now understand the real problem and will try to solve it with a Wicket Session for my authentication of the User!